# if else no printing in variable explorer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am using the Spyder IDE. I wanted to calculate the value and for that, I used the if else condition. but I can't see the calculated value in variable explorer. please suggest me the solution.

```
p = pd.read_excel('Data1.xlsx')
p.head()
a = p.iloc[:12,0].values
b = p.iloc[:12,1].values

c = 200.00
d = 150.00
s = int()
def s(a, b):
       if   a + b < c:
       s = c
       elif a + b > d:
       s = d 
       else:
       s = a + b
return s
print(s)
```

Comment: Your return isn't inside the function, and you're also not running the function with any numbers.

Answer (score 0):

What i wrote previously was wrong, here is a better answer.
EDIT:
you are trying to print the function. it doesn't work that way.

Try this:

```
def s(a, b):
       if   a + b < c:
           s = c
       elif a + b > d:
           s = d 
       else:
           s = a + b
       print(s)
s()
```

Comment: He is printing "s" and not "s()"

Comment: and your indentation is still wrong - if, elif, else : -> indent more

Answer (score 0):

```
a=50 #example a
b=100 #example b

c = 200
d = 120
s=int()
def s(a, b):
    if a + b < c:
        s = c
    elif a + b > d:
        s = d 
    else:
        s = a + b

    return s
print(s(a,b))#Use the same arguments as in your def statement
```